# What is the difference between the Method of Characteristics being formulated in terms of $\theta$ & $\alpha$ and $\theta$ & $\nu$?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, ideal-gas

So I'm doing an MSc thesis involving the method of characteristics in rocket nozzles.

My lecture notes have the MoC formulated such that the positive characteristics are defined as:

C+ = Tan ( $\theta+\nu$)

and

C- = Tan ( $\theta-\nu$)

Which is flow angle relative to the centerline axis ($\theta$) and the Prandtl-Meyer expansion angle ($\nu$). I've previously found a few papers that use this formulation, and its the one that Anderson principally uses in his *Modern Compressible Flow* - although he freely mixes the use of the $\nu$ and $\mu$ equations:

C+ = Tan($\theta+\mu$) or Tan ($\theta+\alpha$)

C- = Tan($\theta-\mu$) or Tan($\theta-\mu$)

Where both $\mu$ and $\alpha$ are the mach angle, sin^-1 (1/M).

This latter formulation is the one given in Zucrow's *Gas Dynamics* exclusively.

Is it because that the $\nu$ formulation is for flows with a free pressure boundary, and $\mu$ or $\alpha$ for internal flows with physical boundaries? This would make sense since a lot of the papers that the $\nu$ formulation crops up in are dealing with the MOC and formulation of aerospike nozzle contours - but it doesnt make sense with my professor giving this notation for internal flows as well.

Or is it simply a difference in describing the characteristic geometry and compatability equations?

I'd appreciate it if anyone could shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

The first equation refers to the invariants themselves.  Along a characteristic curve,
$$
C_\pm = \tan(\theta \pm \nu)
$$
is constant.  The *slope* of that curve, when it leaves the surface, is given by
$$
\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)_0^\pm = \tan(\theta \pm \mu).
$$
If the characteristic curves do not intersect, they are simply straight lines extending from the surface. Since the slopes do not change along these lines, they can be treated as invariants as well. However, if the characteristic curves *do* intersect, $C_\pm$ remains the same, but the slopes of the lines change.